# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I need help with connecting SQL server and Java. I've added the jdbc driver in eclipse but keep getting this error. Still pretty new to java and SQL server so any help, tips, suggestions would greatly be appreciated. Here is the code I'm using. Not sure if it matters but I'm using SQL Server 2014.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DBTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://MACBOOK\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;DatabaseName=ConnectionTest";
        String user = "testing";
        String pass = "test";

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, user, pass);         
    }
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: remove     `microsoft:`

Answer (score 0):

try changing you `dbUrl`to:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://MACBOOK:1433;DatabaseName=ConnectionTest
```

The connection string should be in the format

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]
```

according to [microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks guys, that seem to fix 1 problem.. Now I'm getting

Comment: The TCP/IP connection to the host MACBOOK, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)

Comment: first of all make sure that the host of the database is MACBOOK. You could also use the ip address instead of the hostname. Then make sure the instance of your db is running. Then check in the options that it is actually accepting tcp connections. If all these is checked and you still have a problem than check the hosts pc firewall settings and unblock the 1433 port.

Comment: I thought that I did all that. I'll check it over tonight when I get home. Thanks for the tips

Comment: @Steve if you find an answer helpful you can upvote it and accept it